# Сумма во всех листах, если значения в заданных ячейках равно

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть 4 листа. В каждом разное количество ячеек, но примерно по 100. У каждой ячейки в столбце **А** свое значение и в соседнем столбце **B** цифра.

Пытаюсь написать формулу, но не выходит. Суть в том, что мне нужна общая сумма со всех ячеек **B** всех листов, если **А** = "СЫР"

Пример таков, но как связать все листы и сделать перебор по каждой ячейке непонятно

[image: пример]

Answer (score 2):

Вот для примера `=СУММЕСЛИ(A:A;"СЫР";B:B)+СУММЕСЛИ(Лист2!A:A;"СЫР";B:B)` это если по быстрому

Comment: немного не выходит соединить все листы таким способом, но формула до начала второго СУММЕСЛИ отличная, на калькуляторе прибавить 4 числа не составило труда. Спасибо)

Comment: Во второй `СУММЕСЛИ` нужно указать правильное название листа  и диапазону столбца *В* тоже не забыть записать название этого листа. И в третьей, и в четвертой.